# How can I get the position of a label?

Tags: c#, winforms, position, label

I am supposed to change the position of three labels (ex: `label1` is going to be in `label2`'s position) randomly every time I press a button.

So I decided to take the location of the labels and store them in an array. However, I don't know how to get a label's position. I tried saying `double position = label1.location.X;` but it didn't work.

Comment: is this winforms ? asp.net ? wpf ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia winforms

Comment: Are the labels in fixed positions on the form and you are just swapping their order?

Comment: @Brian yes that's right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get the values using

```
label1.Left, label1.Top
```

set the values using

```
label1.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Do not forget to include

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing; // to use System.Drawing.Point(Label.Left, Label.Top)
```

I've written the code that I hope should help you to get the idea.
Click on the label to get its coordinates.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

class LabelForm : Form
{
    Label label1;
    //
    public LabelForm()
    {
        label1 = new Label();
        label1.Text = "ClickMe";
        label1.Location = new Point(10, 10); // This is the place where you set the location of your label. Currently, it is set to 10, 10.
        label1.Click += new EventHandler(labelClick);
        Controls.Add(label1);
    }
    //
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LabelForm lf = new LabelForm();
        Application.Run(lf);
    }
    //
    protected void labelClick(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This is how you can get label's positions
        int left = label1.Left;
        int top = label1.Top;
        MessageBox.Show("Left position of the label: " + left
            + "\nTop position of the label: " + top,
            "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

Then just use randomizer to set the values to Point(x, y). Note, that you should also check the width and height of your window and subtract the width and height of your label not to go beyond window borders.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `Bounds` property, it's an object of type `Rectangle` which has the width, height and x, y coordinates of the component.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx

That is assuming you're working with the winform class `Label`

EDIT: A simpler property to use is Location

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx

If you just look at the msdn docs for `Label` you'll find there are numerous ways to get that data.

Comment: Bounds gives the location, but you can't actually move the control with those. You have to either set Location to a new Point or change Label.Left and Label.Top.

Answer (score 1):

```
Label.Left, Label.Top
```

Location is just a Point struct that can't be modified.